# WP_Query and OR condition - Expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get post from DB if the post has a meta_value in a pool of values.

Here my code:

```
$carConditions = get_option('car-type');

if (count($carConditions) == 0) {
    return null;
}

$conditions = array_keys($carConditions);

$query_args = [
    'post_type'   => 'vehicle',
    'post_status' => 'publish',       
    'meta_value'  => [
        [
            'key'     => 'car_condition',
            'value'   => $conditions,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        ]
    ]
];
```

So basically I need to check if the post has `car_condition` set to one of `used` or `km0`.
If I run the code above I get:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   array given in /home/vagrant/www/Auto/wp-includes/wp-db.php on
>   line 1166

If I just query by one condition it works:

```
$query_args = [
        'post_type'   => 'vehicle',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'    => 'car_condition',
        'meta_value'  => 'used',
    ];
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here how I solved.
Basically a simple foreach that fetch all the car conditions:

```
$query_args = [
    'post_type'   => 'vehicle',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
];
$metaQuery = [
    'relation' => 'OR'
];
foreach ($conditions as $condition) {
    $metaQuery[] = [
        'key'     => 'car_condition',
        'value'   => $condition,
        'compare' => '='
    ];
}
$query_args['meta_query'] = $metaQuery;
```